# Submit button with a condition

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm looking for creating a form with an e-mail send

first of all I chose a contact with a "select"

and after that I can send the message to a mail address connected with this "select"

When a select and option, the submit send a mail to this mail in the option
In the example i have a SCRIPT which get my mail (in the select)
and on the submit, it supposed to send in the adresse selected.

```html
 <script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("agence");
    }
    </script>

    <Form action="mailto:youraddr@domain.tld" method="GET">
          <label for="Name" class="fcf-label">Votre Agence</label>
          <select name="agence" id="agence-select">
            <option value="">Sélection</option>
            <option id="agence" value="g.champagnat@verandasetpergolas.com">Maurepas 78</option>
    
            <option id="agence" value="d.quaziz@verandasetpergolasbl.com">Villebon-sur-Yvette 91</option>
          </select>
    
          <label for="Email" class="fcf-label">Message</label>
          <input type="email" id="Email" name="Email" class="fcf-form-control" required>
    
   
    
          <input type="submit" value="Envoyer">
        </form>
```

[image]

Comment: dog and hamster are not valid email addresses. What do you mean by `connected`?

Comment: "Submit button with a condition": which condition? Your question isn't clear.

Comment: You need to check some condition before submit?

Comment: Hi i updated my script. What i want is getting the mail selected and put it on the submit.. i want to make a condition (if i select a mail then it'll send it on this mail selected)  but i don't know how to do it

Comment: @saif-ejjilali I've got it. I updated my answer please check

Answer (score 0):

you can attach `onchange` event and then replace `action` of form in your change method:

```js
function myFunction(selectbox) {
   if(selectbox.value){
      document.getElementById("myform").action = "mailto:" + selectbox.value;
   
      console.log('action form is:', document.getElementById("myform").action)
   }
 }
```

```html
<Form id="myform" action="mailto:youraddr@domain.tld" method="GET">
        <label for="Name" class="fcf-label">Votre Agence</label>
        <select name="agence" onchange="myFunction(this)" id="agence-select">
            <option value="">Sélection</option>
            <option  value="g.champagnat@verandasetpergolas.com">Maurepas 78</option>

            <option  value="d.quaziz@verandasetpergolasbl.com">Villebon-sur-Yvette 91</option>
        </select>

        <label for="Email" class="fcf-label">Message</label>
        <input type="email" id="Email" name="Email" class="fcf-form-control" required>



        <input type="submit" value="Envoyer">
    </Form>
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to change `action="mailto:youraddr@domain.tld"` to a value that the user have selected in a select list.

Comment: @SaifEjjilali Has your problem been solved?